# Node.js control flow understanding

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to know control flow in Node.js. But it's too hard for me.

I'm making the google alert crawler using [`google-alerts-api`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-alerts-api) npm.
I get alert's name and alert's rss from this npm. And following is my expected flow.

1. Get `name` and `rss` from the google alerts
2. Push `name` in `result` array
3. Request `rss` and get XML document.
4. Parse XML to JSON and get `entry list`
5. Looping `entry list`, get `title` and `href`

   - `entry list` consists of entries contained `title` and `href`
6. Push `title` and `href` in `result` array
7. When I call `get_result`, I can get above `result` array.

My expected result array is like below. Because I'll push this result at spreadsheet and that api should use like that.

```
[ [name1], [title], [href], [title], [href], ....
, [name2], [title], [href], [title], [href], ...
, ... ]
```

My code

```
const alerts = require('google-alerts-api');
const config = require('./config.js');
const parser = require('xml2json');
const request = require('request')
const Entities = require('html-entities').AllHtmlEntities;

alerts.configure({
    mail: config.mail,
    password: config.pass
});

externalCaller();
function externalCaller(){
    getResult().then(function(arr){
        console.log(arr);
    });
}

var result = [];

function getResult(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        alerts.sync((err) => {
            if(err) return console.log(err);
            const alertList = alerts.getAlerts();
            alertList.reduce(async function(lastPromise, elem){
                await lastPromise;
                var name = elem.name;
                var rss = elem.rss;
                if(name != config.mail){
                    result.push(['']);
                    result.push([name]);
                    result.push(['']);
                    return getXML(rss)
                        .then(printElem);
                }
            }, Promise.resolve());
            resolve(result);
        });
    });
}



function getXML(rssUrl){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        request(rssUrl, function (error, response, body) {
            if(error || (response && response.statusCode != 200)){
                console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
                console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
                reject(error);
            }
            json = parser.toJson(body);
            parsedJson = JSON.parse(json);
            entry = parsedJson.feed.entry;
            if(entry)
                resolve(entry);
        });
    });
}
function printElem(entry){
    entry.forEach(function(entry){
        title = Entities.decode(entry.title.$t);
        title = title.replace(/<b>|<\/b>/g, '');
        result.push([title]);
        result.push([entry.link.href]);
    });
}
```

How can I code correctly?